# Android OS Development. How to add file to output directory

Tags: android, operating-system, build-process

This question is in regards to development of the OS itself, not any application.

I am working on the RIL-DAEMON for an embedded system and I have created the driver source for my modem and added the Android.mk file and the source is included and built by the system. Now I am trying to work out how to get the file to the correct output directory.

For now, it only appears in the symbols/lib in the target out directory. I can manually copy it of course and can create the image to load to the target or I have used ADB to push it to the development board during initial testing.

What I would like is for the lib file to be in the target out system/lib directory after the build.

There is a libreference-ril.so file that comes with the source and I can see this in the symbols and system lib directories. I can't for the life of me figure out how to add my ril.so file to the build system so that it ends up in the final output.

The symbols files have all the debug information and the final output is smaller as the debug information appears to be stripped from it.

If anyone knows how to include this file in the output it would be most appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else here is the answer I found elsewhere.

You have to add your own library entry to the packages in the device.mk file.

Once I did this the file appeared in the output directory.